# How to update the content inside a list in c#

Tags: list

I have a class as follow:

```
public class student
{
  public string studentID { get; set; }
  public string studentName { get; set; }
  public string studentGender { get; set; }
  public string studentCGP { get; set; }
}

List<student> students = new List<student>();
```

..... I had added some data into the students List mention above, except for the data to the **studentCGP**.

After my other calculation for the studentCGP data, how do I put the data back to respectively? I'll have the studentID and studentCGP in hand.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>using Linq...</strike>

```
var student = students.Find( x => x.studentID == idValue );
student.studentCGP = cgpValue;
```

Seems pretty trivial... am I missing something in the question?

Comment: That's not actually LINQ; `Find()` is a method on `List<T>` which accepts a `Predicate<T>` (which of course can be a lambda.)

Comment: Doh... you are right of course. Originally `Find` was `First`, and I intended to add the using reference. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: opps... I forgot to mention, the code is use in WP7 development. it seem the Find Method is not available in SL. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
students.Single(o => o.studentID == idValue).studentCGP = cgpValue;
```

There is a number of functions that you can use, just choose the one that suits you the best. For example you can use also First, Last etc.